# Upgrade Does Not Pass [Executed: Begin Upgrade to 4.7.19]

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 4.7.18 to 4.7.29.  I am doing this on a development server and I have created a sub-domain for it and made sure that the site is running before I attempt to do the upgrade.

I have tried the upgrade several times (having restored the database and reset paths) and I still get stuck at the begging saying - [Executed: Begin Upgrade to 4.7.19].

The url I am at is `https://[subdomain].[domain.org]//civicrm/upgrade/queue/runner?reset=1&qrid=CRM_Upgrade`

I have PHP 7.0.22 on my test server and MySQL 5.7.21.  Basically, what comes out the box with an Amazon Ubuntu AMI.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What is in the civicrm log file?  Some schema changes take a while depending on your table sizes and the log may show more detail than the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I used `drush civicrm-upgrade-db` and it appears to be working perfectly.

I had already put the  4.7.29 files in /sites/all/modules/civicrm so only the database had to be upgraded.

-Josh